# How to sync audio metadata (e.g. ID3) between file copies?

Tags: audio, synchronization, backup, metadata, id3

I have thousands of audio files in mp3, m4a, ape, flac formats on my PC. I made a copy (backup) of them to an external disk drive.

If I changed the metadata (e.g. ID3) of some audio files on my PC, what is the best way to sync the changed metadata to the external disk drive?

File syncing program may be a choice, but copying the whole file is much slower. I want to sync the metadata only.

Answer (score 1):

Where metadata is stored differs drastically between file formats (ID3/MP3 and APE: start or end of file; MP4 and FLAC/Vorbis and RIFF: anywhere), especially if you modify it (instead of providing it right away when creating the file) - just try it yourself to see how filesizes can change when you modify metadata in each file format. And how it begins/ends before your modification and how afterwards.

At the end of the day it's much easier to "just" copy the whole file if it differs at all than to first analyze which file format is there and which metadata system(s) it uses and what to which extent has changed in there.